# Error launching Android Studio 2.2 Preview 1

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, ide

I downloaded and extracted ZIP of Android Studio 2.2 Prev 1. I am using Ubuntu on my system and on opening studio.sh using terminal i received this message:

```
 Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "fi")
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue... Running Ubunutu-64 16.04

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that if you edit the studio.sh and change the first line from:

## !/bin/sh

to

## !/bin/bash

Android Studio 2.2 should launch

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be a bug in Android Studio installation files.

Comment: This really works but I still think it was a bug for AS 2.2 Preview 1. Hope Google will fix it sooner or later.

Comment: It worked for me from Ubuntu, just by running $bash studio.sh, I'm using zsh as my default shell.

Answer (score 0):

Along with changing 
**!/bin/sh**
to

**!/bin/bash**

also use $**bash studio.sh** to start Android Studio